# Loop through DOM elements with JQuery to assign a click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to loop through the DOM with JQuery, and add a click handler to multiple parent elements that contain a child that will also be given a `slideToggle()`. I have the logic working fine when I add the click handlers manually, but now I need to be able to dynamically do this to multiple parent elements.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="map-poi-nav">

   <ul class="map-poi-nav-dropdown">

      //Parent #1
      <li class="sub-menu-link" id="sub-menu-link-1">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/ADc.svg"> Activities
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-menu">
         <ul class="sub-menu-list" id="sub-menu-list-1">
            <li><a><span>•</span>Golden State Park</a></li>
            <li><a><span>•</span>Sunrise Oaks City Park</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>

   </ul>

   <ul class="map-poi-nav-dropdown">

     //Parent #2
      <li class="sub-menu-link" id="sub-menu-link-2">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/ADc.svg"> Dining
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-menu">
         <ul class="sub-menu-list" id="sub-menu-list-2">
            <li><a><span>•</span>The Loft Grill</a></li>
            <li><a><span>•</span>Fish Grill & Bar</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>

</div>
```

Basically, you click on `.sub-menu-link` to `slideToggle()` `.sub-menu-list`.

Here is the JS that I have working so far. It targets the id's manually currently, which feels gross:

```
$('#sub-menu-link-1').click(function() {
    $('#sub-menu-list-1').slideToggle(100);
    $(this).toggleClass('active-menu-link');
});

$('#sub-menu-link-2').click(function() {
    $('#sub-menu-list-2').slideToggle(100);
    $(this).toggleClass('active-menu-link');
});
```

My apologies if this is something very apparent to do in JQuery. I am not at all familiar with it, and it just so happens to be a requirement of this project.

Answer (score 0):

you could  simply use below code.

select all list items with class name and add listener. click will be attached to all elements

```
$('.sub-menu-link').click(function() {
    $(this).slideToggle(100);
    $(this).toggleClass('active-menu-link');
});
```

Comment: This is incorrect. OP doesn't want to call `slideToggle` on the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

You already have classes, so just use them instead of the `id`s: use `this` to refer to the clicked element, `.next()` to get the next sibling (the `li.sub-menu`), and `.find('.sub-menu-list')` to get to the `ul` you want to toggle:

```js
$('.sub-menu-link').click(function() {
  const $subMenuList = $(this).next().find('.sub-menu-list');
  console.log($subMenuList.text().trim());
  $subMenuList.slideToggle(100);
  $(this).toggleClass('active-menu-link');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map-poi-nav">

  <ul class="map-poi-nav-dropdown">

    //Parent #1
    <li class="sub-menu-link" id="sub-menu-link-1">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/ADc.svg"> Activities
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu">
      <ul class="sub-menu-list" id="sub-menu-list-1">
        <li><a><span>•</span>Golden State Park</a></li>
        <li><a><span>•</span>Sunrise Oaks City Park</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <ul class="map-poi-nav-dropdown">

    //Parent #2
    <li class="sub-menu-link" id="sub-menu-link-2">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/ADc.svg"> Dining
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu">
      <ul class="sub-menu-list" id="sub-menu-list-2">
        <li><a><span>•</span>The Loft Grill</a></li>
        <li><a><span>•</span>Fish Grill & Bar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) like so:

```
$(".sub-menu-link").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".sub-menu-link").slideToggle(100);
    $(this).toggleClass("active-menu-link");
})
```

Or you can chain them and use ES6 arrow syntax to make it more concise:

```
$(".sub-menu-link").click(() => $(this).toggleClass("active-menu-link").next(".sub-menu-link").slideToggle(100));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this if your list and link ids have similiar pattern as in the code you have shown

```
$('#sub-menu-link').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("sub-menu-link", "")
    $('#sub-menu-list-'+ id).slideToggle(100);
    $(this).toggleClass('active-menu-link');
});
```